How to configure Morgan to skip logging for small response times
I have searched through the docs and threads but can't seem to find a way to configure Morgan to skip logging based on response times.  I would like to do something like the following, but can figure out how to get the response time that Morgan already calculates.  Any help would be appreciated.
app.use(morgan("common", {
    skip: function(req, res) { 
        if(res.statusCode > 400 || res.respondTime > 200){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }       
})); 


I found what I needed from this article.  It doesn't utilize Morgan, but the results are very similar and perfect for what I need.
https://ipirozhenko.com/blog/measuring-requests-duration-nodejs-express/
